# What is the difference between the two Police Stations?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

The police station public works project just became available in my town.  There are two of them - modern and classic.

What are the differences / similarities between the two, and are there things exclusive to either that the other one doesn't offer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionally, they are completely the same - they offer the same lost and found bin, and Copper and Booker will appear at both. The difference is purely aesthetical - so pick whichever one you feel goes best with the look you are trying to create for your town!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?  Booker and Cooper will 100% spawn at both?  And which one looks like the one from the Gamecube version - classic or modern?

Comment: I am not sure what else to tell you, other than the look, they are exactly the same. I didn't really play the Gamecube version, so I can't tell you which looks more like that one.